# Error while installing jitterbit client installation

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have to install jitterbit client .I have downloaded jitterbit-client-4.0.7.14-enterprise-trial-linux-rpm .I I tried.

```
sudo rpm -Uvh jitterbit-client-4.0.7-14.e.i386.rpm
```

it gives:

```
  rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
  rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
  error: Failed dependencies:
  /bin/sh is needed by jitterbit-client-4.0.7-14.e.i386
```

I have installed 32 bit java version also.  and I tried to convert it into .deb also using alien but its not converted. so what is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the right way to install it in Ubuntu. Ubuntu packet manager is `apt-get` and uses the `deb` packages, not the `rpm` like other distributions.

So, if you don't have a `deb` package for `jitterbit-client` you should install it manually. First install `Alien` with:

```
sudo apt-get install alien rpm debhelper fakeroot binutils
```

Then follow this [instructions](http://www.tonybibbs.com/2008/05/Jitterbit-Client-On-Kubuntu/) these are for an older version but should work for you too.

Comment: I have already installed alien rpm but while converting to .deb
it is giving error:
   `Warning: Skipping conversion of scripts in package jitterbit-client: postinst postrm
Warning: Use the --scripts parameter to include the scripts.
jitterbit-client-4.0.7-14.e.i386.rpm is for architecture i386 ; the package cannot be built on this system
`
     I know I am using 32 bit jitterbit client and my os is 64 bit .but jiterbit client is only available in 32 bit. so how I can install?

Comment: Looks like your system is not `i386`. What kind of system are you using?

Comment: Yes my system is not i386. I am using 64 bit Ubuntu but the above problem is solved .I converted it on another i386 system. and used Thank you for your response.